# Opening file on android

Tags: java, android, java-io

i want to open a file that i create in android and allways give me this error, the main problem is when i want to open the file, that the app crash

```
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at menu.menuapp.FrontActivity.confirm(FrontActivity.java:51)
07-29 14:56:09.708: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
```

This is the code to save the file.

```
//Opening the notes file to be write.
    String notes_str = "<resource></resource>"
FileOutputStream notes_file = openFileOutput("notes.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Converting to string the notes_doc
String notes_str = new menu.menuapp.general().xmltostring(notes_doc);
//Saving on the file
notes_file.write(notes_str.getBytes());
//Closing the file.
notes_file.close();
```

This is the code to open the file.

```
File file = new File("notes.xml");
FileInputStream notes_xml = new FileInputStream(file);
byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)notes_xml.available()];
//The information will be content on the buffer.

notes_xml.read(fileContent);

String strContent = new String(fileContent);
    notes_xml.close();
```

Comment: Can you paste your full stack trace? Your app chashes when? Opening or saving he file?

Comment: Do you have permissions set to access the SDCard?

Comment: @Doomsknight I thinks so because if i can write, I assume i can read

Comment: @Doomsknight, this app is writing to internal storage, so it already has permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying the path correctly when you open the file for read.  The constructor you use for [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) requires a full path, not just a file name.

If you write the file with [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), then I suggest you read it back with [openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29).  That way you're more likely to get all the parameters right.

For more guidance on reading and writing files, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Also, your filename is different when reading and writing.  You should define that in a string resource or at least a static final.

Comment: Thanks the problem was on the difference between the openFileOutput and the File!